# Trouble integrating next-auth, MongoDB, and Google OAuth

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I am building a web app that requires user login with user data being saved to a MongoDB database. When logging in with the MongoDB code, it just resulted in a login loop with no signs of error. I created a brand new project and scaffolded the authentication part of my web app and found the same problem.

What I ultimately want to achieve is having custom fields in the user model without having to fetch data both from the session and from the database separately.

Is it possible to login with Google and then save the user data to MongoDB? Or is there is any other way of achieving the goal?

Thank you very much. If you need any specifics on the project i'll share them.

Comment: Can you share a code with what you are trying to do? And explain this part better: _What I ultimately want to achieve is having custom fields in the user model without having to fetch data both from the session and from the database separately._ You want login with google and save user data to MongoDB, you mean to not need to login with google again?